# Spring Boot Annotations, Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf

Are there any Spring examples or projects that contain the annotations `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` in combination with Thymeleaf? I had difficulty solving the datasheet issue through Thymeleaf. So I want to find examples so I can better understand them. If the CRUD project is too great. Thanks

Comment: Post the code which you tried and failed.

Comment: Here is a useful link: https://www.baeldung.com/persistence-with-spring-series

Comment: One more link: https://springframework.guru by John Thompson

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM